# How to launch standard browser out of Java application?

Tags: java, url, browser

how to I open a URL with the systems standard browser with Java?

I currently use this code for opening a specific URL (locally stored html file), which works fine when I run the application with my IDE (Eclipse), but after bundling the software, it doesn't work any more.

```
    url = MainWindow.class.getResource("mySite.html");

    helpMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Any suggestsions?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *but after **bundling** the software, it doesn't work any more.*

You cannot browse to URL's which points to resources inside a JAR file. You need to extract the resource (just get `InputStream` using `getResourceAsStream()`) and store it somewhere else ([as temp file](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?) and then browse it instead.

Comment: No, take the file in your classpath and copy it to your file system somewhere (like as a temp file like BalusC suggested).  Then, you can open the copy in a browser.

Comment: No, just write it to an `OutputStream` the usual Java IO way, which can be `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Sorry for answering that late, but I still couldn't figure out what exactly I have to do.

As suggested, I get the resource as an InputStream, like this:
InputStream s = MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("mySite.html");

But then what?

Comment: Store it as "loose" `File` at local disk file system and finally browse that instead. You can write `InputStream` to `OutputStream` of the `File` using `FileOutputStream` the [usual Java IO way](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/).

Answer (score 0):

Any idea why it doesn't work?
You can try [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/), it has not been updated for a while but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[Bare Bones Browser Launch](http://www.centerkey.com/java/browser/) is a good solution.  It's very easy to use:

```
BareBonesBrowserLaunch.openURL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: His intent is to browse to a HTML file bundled with the application. Besides, this isn't much better than the Java SE builtin `Desktop#browse()`. It's only useful if the client is still on the 5 yrs old Java 5 or earlier.

Comment: Oh neato, I didn't even know that existed!